# Error for autocomplete is not a function mvc4 and ajax & Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Autocomplete not a function error show for code shown below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please, post your code here instead of giving screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Try adding full URL including `http:` like `http://code.jquery...`
and make sure the resources are being loaded.